# AutoIt - ControlClick follows mouse coords

Tags: autoit

I am knew to AutoIt and I try to understand the ControlClick function. But when I use it, it follows my mouse coords instead of the coords in my window and only when my mouse is over this window.

I just try to learn the language and I use a code that I made few years ago (just to explain the context ).

I know that my handle is the good one, and I checked the coords with the Window Info.

```
AutoItSetOption("MouseCoordMode", 1)
Global $hwnd = WinGetHandle("[CLASS:GLFW30]")
ControlClick($hwnd, "", $hwnd, $button, 1, $x, $y) ; $vars are declared in my code
```

Any question or solution ?

Comment: What is your problem? You know this? MouseCoordMode Sets the way coords are used in the mouse functions, either absolute coords or coords relative to the current active window:
0 = relative coords to the active window
1 = (default) absolute screen coordinates
2 = relative coords to the client area of the active window